# Java Download ZIP for update

Tags: java, download, cloud, onedrive

Temporarily I want to provide updates for my program in a cloud (e.g. OneDrive). I tried some code variation. Some of them produce an empty file that cannot be opened. With some I get an empty ZIP. With all cloud services I do not get a direct link (like https://[...]/latest.zip).

```
            File file = new File (updatePath, "latest.zip");

            try{
                ReadableByteChannel rbc=Channels.newChannel(updateURL.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOut.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
                rbc.close();
            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

How can I download the ZIP WITHOUT including an external API. And can I get a) the filename of the file to download and b) the state of the download?

Comment: There's some confusion here. You want to upload the update then later download it?

Comment: @g00se, I lose the connection to the local source code after publishing. Changes must be transferred. The cloud serves as an interface. The program independently searches for updates (in the cloud). I upload updated versions to the cloud.

Comment: I think the general answer is that if you use proprietary cloud platforms, you need to use their API to access it programmatically. You will generally need 3rd party software as soon as you move away from open standards, and sometimes you'll even need it if the protocol is not very simple.

Comment: Nah ... are there alternative ways to provide downloadable content — without own server infrastructure?

Comment: Not that I know of, other than 'pastebin' style sites and image upload sites. At least not for free